# Insert string(containing timezone) into datetimeoffset column in SQL server 2008 through Java program

Tags: java, sql-server

I have to insert data(which is also containing the timezone, i.e. 2013-01-19 00:00:00 +0530) which is in String form and the datatype of the column is DATETIMEOFFSET. I have tried both java.util.date and sql.date but could not find any solution.

Comment: Which JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: jdbc:sqlserver(or sqljdbc4.jar)

Comment: Well that sounds like it's the Microsoft driver - which means my answer should be fine for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the [Microsoft JDBC driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx), you can use the [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff427229.aspx) class, constructing instances with the [`valueOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff427231.aspx) method.

You'll need to parse the value out into local time and offset (in order to pass the two parts separately) but that shouldn't be too bad using `SimpleDateFormat`. (The `Z` format specifier in `SimpleDateTimeFormat` will handle offsets like +0530.) Alternatively, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) which will make life easier still, as it will allow you to parse to a `DateTime` which lets you get the offset as well as the local time in one go. I would personally use Joda Time and create a method to convert from a `DateTime` to a `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: one more doubt...what should i use for setting value of datetimeoffset object into the statement....statement.setDate() or statement.setTimestamp()

Comment: @abhijeet: You could probably use `setObject`, or use `SQLServerPreparedStatement.setDateTimeOffset`.

Comment: One more question...while fetching from DatetimeOffset column in DB...i can use DateTimeOffset object = (DateTimeOffset )resultSet.getObject(columnname)??

Comment: I suspect so, but you're in a better position to check it than I am.